# Understanding the cause of exception

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, nullreferenceexception

I had the following in my event log from my web server. Does anybody know what might be wrong? I researched on the Internet, but found nothing in terms of why it happens. I don't ask what NULL exception is. I very well know that. All I ask is that this exception is thrown from ASP.NET classes. Since I can't see Microsoft's implementation, I just want to know if anyone else has ever encountered the same exception with similar stack trace and how they handled this.

```
Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sample.Test..ctor()
   at __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_qquiiyt1.Create_ASP_test_aspx()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: I know what it is, but I don't understand why this happens. These calls are done by ASP.net, not me.

Comment: What is the `Test` class? Does it have any initialization or a constructor? Can you get this to fail in a Debug configuration so that you would have line numbers available to see where the crash occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a class named Test, the null reference is being thrown from the constructor of that class.   Paste the Test class.

Answer (score 0):

This type of Exception throws when a reference type has no instance.

For example:

```
List<CustomType> list;
CustomType item = new CustomType();
list.Add(item);
```

A `NullReferenceException` will occur when you add a new item to the list (Because `list` has no instance).

For your problem specifically you'll have to investigate at what point the exception occurred.

The stack trace tells you:

```
Sample.Test..ctor()
```

So I would look at that constructor.

You can use `Log4Net` which can provide with additional Assembly information which may help in identifying at what point the exception occured, also look for a `try/catch block`, in your case you've caught `NullReferenceException` or the generic `Exception` class which is bad practice.

Comment: You guys misunderstand me. I very well know what null reference exception is. The stack trace I show contains methods asp.net calls. Why these methods produce null reference exception is the question.

Comment: One of your objects has no instance.  Asking why it crashes is almost impossible for us to debug for you when we don't have the full code/not familiar with your system/you haven't told us why you think this happens.

Comment: These are asp.net calls. Someone might have encountered the same expection with this call stack.

Comment: I would look at the constructor in `Sample.Test`